# Should I remove Uploads/ from .gitignore?

Tags: git, file-upload

I have taken over managing a website and am having issues adding a new product to the site. All images are stored in an uploads folder, and when using the admin panel created by the old developer, it has a file upload process that adds files to this folder. However, for one category of product, it does not work. I can manually add the product information to the database through Sequel Pro, and everything works, except there's obviously no way to upload the pictures to the path that the code requires. I would just add them to an uploads folder to follow the correct path, but uploads/ is listed in the .gitignore file.

Would removing uploads/ from .gitignore have any negative repercussions? My worry is that it will overwrite the existing uploads directory, and then possibly interfere with the existing uploading process.
I don't know why uploads was included on gitignore in the first place, but I'm sure the other developer must have had his reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Typically `uploads/` is not a directory where your code code belongs. It's stuff that is generated from use, not required for use. The reason it's often ignored in version control systems is that tracking changes to everything your user might change just isn't needed. Based on this, I'd not recommend you stop ignoring it.

Because Git specifically will store a copy of every change in the objects it may actually be a bad idea to not ignore and commit files from this directory. Your repository will grow for no useful reason. It's also not likely that your gitignore file has anything to do with your actual problem.

Chances are when installing from the repo in a new location either the `uploads/` directory was not created because when cloning it didn't exist in the repo or the permissions for that directory do not allow adding a subdirectory when they upload to this new category.

For the first issue, consider that Git doesn't track the directory, it tracks files in it. If your project has an empty and ignored `uploads/` directory it won't be committed and therefor won't be created when cloning. You'll either have to remember to make this directory manually when cloning, or a common practice is to add a `.gitkeep` file to the directory and commit that file. This will cause the file to be created when cloning, and preserve file structure. You can commit a file that is ignored, and changes beyond that commit will continue to be ignored. To do this use the `-f/--force` flag with `git add`.

For the second issue if your script is trying to create a new file or subdirectory within `uploads/` make sure the user the **script** is running as has permission to do this. What that user is depends on your system, but should be easily found on the great Google machine.

Lastly, committing files in this directory should not overwrite existing files. Matching names may cause you frustration in pulling, or committing new changes but Git is usually good about warning heavily or downright refusing to just blindly eliminate your changes.